# Elasticsearch error: cluster_block_exception [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)], flood stage disk watermark exceeded

Tags: elasticsearch

When trying to post documents to Elasticsearch as normal I'm getting this error:

```
cluster_block_exception [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];
```

I also see this message on the Elasticsearch logs:

```
flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded ... all indices on this node will marked read-only
```

Comment: I just ran into this problem when you put this question. ES discuss saying freeing up memory

Answer (score 518, accepted):

This happens when Elasticsearch thinks the disk is running low on space so it puts itself into read-only mode.

By default Elasticsearch's decision is based on the **percentage** of disk space that's free, so on big disks this can happen even if you have many gigabytes of free space.

The flood stage watermark is 95% by default, so on a 1TB drive you need at least 50GB of free space or Elasticsearch will put itself into read-only mode.

For docs about the flood stage watermark see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/disk-allocator.html.

The right solution depends on the context - for example a production environment vs a development environment.

### Solution 1: free up disk space

Freeing up enough disk space so that more than 5% of the disk is free will solve this problem. Elasticsearch won't automatically take itself out of read-only mode once enough disk is free though, you'll have to do something like this to unlock the indices:

```
$ curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://[YOUR_ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT]:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

### Solution 2: change the flood stage watermark setting

Change the `"cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage"` setting to something else. It can either be set to a lower percentage or to an absolute value. Here's an example of how to change the setting from [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/disk-allocator.html):

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "100gb",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "50gb",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "10gb",
    "cluster.info.update.interval": "1m"
  }
}
```

Again, after doing this you'll have to use the curl command above to unlock the indices, but after that they should not go into read-only mode again.

Comment: Hi. But I am getting this error, even when there is enough free space in my system. Are there other reasons which could be reporting this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue, even though I have 82.43% disk available. I fix it with the curl command but after a few days I am getting the same.

Comment: @SankalpaTimilsina did you get the answer, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: You might get the following error using curl command `curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`. It means you don't have Elasticsearch configured for TLS. So just use http instead

Comment: Make sure you restart elastic search after freeing up diskspace.

Comment: I tried the Solution 1 and Worked fine. I was using ES7 along for Magento Development.

Comment: For those getting "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_all/_settings]", just add the elastic credentials as ``-u username:password`` at the end of the curl commands suggested in the replies to this post.

Answer (score 241):

By default, Elasticsearch installed goes into read-only mode when you have less than 5% of free disk space. If you see errors similar to this:

> Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Forbidden:   [403]
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked
>   by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete
>   (api)];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by:
>   [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"},"status":403}

Or in **/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch.log** you can see logs similar to:

> flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on
>   [nCxquc7PTxKvs6hLkfonvg][nCxquc7][/usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0]
>   free: 15.3gb[4.1%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only

Then you can fix it by running the following commands:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so frustrated. The second curl command you posted worked for me!

Comment: Worked for me, ran into it with a local docker elastic container.

Answer (score 64):

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

FROM

https://techoverflow.net/2019/04/17/how-to-fix-elasticsearch-forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api/

Comment: I'm getting a `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [null] and no indices exist"` with your command, any idea ?

Comment: Thanks! My disk was running out of space. Even after I freed up some space, the problem still remained. This command solved my problem!

Comment: This is the correct solution for modern Elasticsearch versions. However, it didn't work with `_all`. I had to apply it to each index manually.

Comment: @rubik can you please mention how you "apply it to each index manually"?  I am new on Elasticsearch and facing same issue where _all is not working.

Comment: @rom Sure. Just replace `_all` with the index name, and repeat the request for each index.

Answer (score 43):

This error is usually observed when your machine is low on disk space.
Steps to be followed to avoid this error message

1. Resetting the read-only index block on the index:

   ```
   $ curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'

   Response
   ${"acknowledged":true}
   ```
2. Updating the low watermark to at least 50 gigabytes free, a high watermark of at least 20 gigabytes free, and a flood stage watermark of 10 gigabytes free, and updating the information about the cluster every minute

   ```
    Request
    $curl -X PUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "50gb", "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "20gb", "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "10gb", "cluster.info.update.interval": "1m"}}'

     Response
     ${
      "acknowledged" : true,
      "persistent" : { },
      "transient" : {
      "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
      "allocation" : {
      "disk" : {
        "watermark" : {
          "low" : "50gb",
          "flood_stage" : "10gb",
          "high" : "20gb"
        }
      }
    }
   }, 
   "info" : {"update" : {"interval" : "1m"}}}}}
   ```

After running these two commands, you must run the first command again so that the index does not go again into read-only mode

Answer (score 10):

Only changing the settings with the following command did not work in my environment:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

I had to also ran the Force Merge API command:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_forcemerge?pretty"
```

ref: [Force Merge API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html)

Answer (score 2):

Even if the computer storage is revived above 95% the issue will still persist.

Short term solution is to increase kibana limit above 95%.This solution works in Windows only.

```
a. Create a json file with following parameters


{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "90%",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "95%",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "97%"
  }
}

b.Name it anything ,e.g : json.txt

c.Type following command in command prompt

>curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @json.txt

d.Following output is received.

{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "disk" : {
            "watermark" : {
              "low" : "90%",
              "flood_stage" : "97%",
              "high" : "95%"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "transient" : { }
}

e.Create another json file with following parameter


{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
}

f.Name it anything ,e.g : json1.txt

g.Type following command in command prompt

>curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/*/_settings?expand_wildcards=all" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @json1.txt

h.You should get following output

{"acknowledged":true}

i.Restart ELK stack/Kibana and the issue should be resolved.
```

Comment: What’s Windows-specific in this solution?

Answer (score 1):

A nice guide from the ELK team:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/disk-usage-exceeded.html

It worked for me with ELK 7.x