# Kibana 6.5.4 Create index pattern stuck

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-6

[image]I am using kibana 6.5.4 to visualise my data in ES but there are sth wrong. 
Firstly, I searched the index "sentiment" and it does exist in my ES;
Secondly, I clicked "Create index pattern";
Finally, it stuck here forever...

Comment: If you open your web console you might see an error in the network requests. I see: `{"message":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];: [cluster_block_exception] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];","statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden"}`

Answer (score 1):

Could be caused to due index permissions.

If it's due to low disk space the following answer is relevant: [Elasticsearch error: cluster_block_exception [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)], flood stage disk watermark exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609417/elasticsearch-error-cluster-block-exception-forbidden-12-index-read-only-all)

Answer (score 1):

updating the cluster and removing blocks from the indices worked for me:

```
curl -X PUT \
  localhost:9200/_all/_settings \
  -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'

curl -X PUT \
  localhost:9200/_cluster/settings \
  -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use developer console and try the following commands the check the existence of the index.

```
 GET <index-pattern>/_search
    {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Also, check your elastic logs for any error.

Comment: I did what you said and it does exist...but I still can not create the index pattern.

Comment: Please share what did you get as an output for the query I mentioned above?