# Curl "(6) Could not resolve host: http"

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I am trying to run this command

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

But this results in this error

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: http
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 5:
null}'
```

I got this command from here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50609418/3259896

I'm am not yet very familiar with curl nor elasticseach, so I'm not sure how to pinpoint the error

If it makes a difference, I am using Windows.

I also tried

```
$ curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

Edit2:

I tried

`curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'`

But now get this error

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@446f2dd5; line: 1, column: 2]"}],"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@446f2dd5; line: 1, column: 2]"},"status":400}curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 5:
null}'
    ^`

I then tried

`curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d "{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}"`

And I got

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@696b36d3; line: 1, column: 3]"}],"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@696b36d3; line: 1, column: 3]"},"status":400}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, in that other SO question, the ES node was a live one so its URL included `https`.

Your localhost ist almost certainly not going to have `https` so change it to `http`:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings \
     -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

Other than that, everything looks okay, provided that your ES *is* running.

When successful, you should receive a simple message:

```
{"acknowledged":true}
```

Edit: go with

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d "{\"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete\": null}"
```

Comment: I tried this but now getting a different error, original question updated with new error