# Kibana throwing 429 (Too many requests) when trying to create an index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana, http-status-code-429

I have an `elasticsearch` index (150kb only) which I want to visualise in kibana. After going to stack management > index patterns > crate new index pattern a 429 (Too many requests) error is being thrown. This is from the browser:

```
Failed to load resource: http://localhost:5601/api/saved_objects/index-pattern the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests)
```

**Why is this happening?** I switched off elasticsearch and kibana and back on but the error persists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that kibana does not really give a good error response. My issue was that elasticsearch was not allowing any changes to be made because it determined that I was running low on storage.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609417/elasticsearch-error-cluster-block-exception-forbidden-12-index-read-only-all) solved the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

In our case we had almost no space left on the disks.

Our solution was to go into Stack Management > Index Management > Select a few indices we no longer needed (eg. old or big), and select manage index, and delete. Afterwards the ES cluster recovered.