# Elasticsearch docker unhealthy due to DB migration

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I had a group of docker containers, one is a MySQL DB, other is a kibana(v7.14) one and the one failling is an enterprise-search container.

I have deployed an angularjs front-end app deploy on other container and the last one is a python back-end

I tried to import a DB in MySQL Workbench from a .sql file(8GB size) but I didn't check the available space, so the import stopped before the end due to lack of space (2 things happen, one i run out of space, the second is that the import says a table was fulled). I fix that problem, but when I tried to "docker-compose up -d". All of them start except the commented, the error is the next (extracted from "docker logs <unhealthy_container_id>" ):

```
 FATAL  Error: Unable to complete saved object migrations for the [.kibana] index. Please check the health of your Elasticsearch cluster and try again. Error: [cluster_block_exception]: index [.kibana_7.14.0_001] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block]
```

Any idea of how to solve this?

I checked the elastic web but I found no error related to this issue.
I tried to delete the DB and restore to the previous state or even create an empty new one but the same issue is happening. Obviously the container keeps unhealthy

Answer (score 0):

**first solution** - try to re-enable write request for all indices.

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

---

**second solution** - remove all indices and restart the migration

1. delete all indices

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/_all"
```

2. restart the migration

This thread can help you to understand issue: [Elasticsearch error: cluster_block_exception [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)], flood stage disk watermark exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609417/elasticsearch-error-cluster-block-exception-forbidden-12-index-read-only-all)