# Elasticsearch indice not being created

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I have a stack of Filebeat->Logstash-Elasticsearch-Kibana. Recently I had an issue with the server disk space and my logs weren't writing for 1 day. Once I got the issue fixed I can't see my logs for this certain day when the whole stack didn't work.
This command doesn't provide my custom index, only system ones.

`$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty | grep 2019.10.17`

What should I do to create index and restore/push logs to it?
Is it the issue of logstash or Elasticsearch?
Looks like logstash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TransportError(403, u'cluster\_block\_exception', u'blocked by: \[FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)\];')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032661/transporterror403-ucluster-block-exception-ublocked-by-forbidden-12-inde)

Comment: I don't have the index at all. How could it be read-only or not read-only?